# jQ Dynamically set div height based on surrounding divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

[I have a schedule page](http://charon.cs.wau.edu/~kwilliam/csdesk) I'd like to reformat depending on the time blocks. For instance: Beatrice is in Mon at 9 and 10. I would like to combine those time blocks to look like 1 block in the browser. I read the schedule from a file and print it to the screen. I want to use jQ to combine them. My thought process: Compare each div to the next one, if they are the same; cnt goes up, I hide the duplicate entries, and make the first entry's height cover all the duplicates.

What I have so far is this:

```
var cnt = 1;
$('.sched-col').each(function(){ //for each column
  $(this).find('.worker').each(function(){ //look for each time block
    if ($(this).html() == $(this).next().html()) { //if block is the same as the next
      cnt++; //increase the count
      $(this).next().css('display', 'none'); //hide the following block
      $(this).css('height', boxH * cnt); //adjust height to cover following block
    }
  });
  cnt = 1; //reset counter for new column
});
```

I know the logic is not actually there. I need to find a name, count the number of blocks with the same name under it, hide those blocks and adjust the height accordingly, and reset the count for each new name. I just need some help to put that into the code.

[My attempt at combining blocks](http://charon.cs.wau.edu/~kwilliam/csdesk2)

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around with code lines, it turns out you have to keep the last entry that has the same name, and stretch that one to fill the space The working code:

```
var boxH = $('.worker').outerHeight();

var cnt = 1; //initial count of first name encounter
$('.sched-col').each(function(){ //for each column
  $(this).find('.worker').each(function(){ //find the worker blocks
    if ($(this).html() == $(this).next().html()) { //if next block is same name
      cnt++; //increase count
      $(this).css('display', 'none'); //remove the current block
    }
    else { //two blocks are not the same name
      $(this).css('height', boxH * cnt); //stretch to cover duplicate block spaces
      cnt = 1; //reset count
    }
  });
});
```